# Laravel package to generate invoices to European users?

Tags: laravel, invoice

I'm looking for a Laravel package that interacts with some provider to allow to generate pro forma invoices when a user make a request and also generate an invoice/receipt to European users after they do a payment in the system.

Do you know any package for that?

Comment: Why don't you build the logic yourself. I created my own simple accounting module in less than 3 days. Once a record is created (Invoice or Proforma) you can run a job that emails the pdf to the user

Comment: Thanks, Im a beninner maybe is a complex process for a beginner so I was looking for some laravel package. the api that you used also allow to generate invoices to European users?